# Changing the location of dataimport.properties used by DataImportHandler

Tags: solr

The DataImportHandler reads the start time stored in conf/dataimport.properties by default. Is it possible to change the location of dataimport.properties so that DataImportHandler can read it from a location other than conf/dataimport.properties?

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in Solr as of the current version. Use a symbolic link as an alternative for now.

You can track this effort in JIRA here:

[SOLR-1970 - need to customize location of dataimport.properties](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1970)